# Chrome extension loading error: Rules file must contain a list. Could not load manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load the extention into chrome but I'm getting this error :
"Rules file must contain a list. Could not load manifest."

Before I moved from manifest v2 to manifest v3 everything worked just fine  however after moving from v2 to v3 the service-worker is showing  this error "unchecked runtime.lastError: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest."  So I have added and declared  webRequestBlocking. But now it gives me the error "Rules file must contain a list. Could not load manifest."

This is the only part of  the code where webrequest is being used:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(handleNewRequest, filter, ['blocking']);
```

This is how my manifest v3 file looks:

```
{
    
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test2",
    "author": "test3",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/icon-off-16.png",
            "32": "icons/icon-off-32.png",
            "48": "icons/icon-off-48.png",
            "128": "icons/icon-off-128.png"
        },
        "default_title": "glagoliziraj"
    },
   
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon-on-16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon-on-32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon-on-48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon-on-128.png"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"  ],

    "declarative_net_request" : {
        "rule_resources" : [{
          "id": "1",
          "enabled": false,
          "path": "rules_1.json"
        }]
        
        },
    
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking ",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest"
       
    ],
    "manifest_version": 3

  
   
}
```

This is how my rule file looks:

```
   {
    "id" : 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action" : { "type" : "block" },
    "condition" : {
      "urlFilter" : "||google.com/",
      "resourceTypes" : ["main_frame"]
    },
 
    "testList" : [{
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules_1.json"
      }, {
        "id": "ruleset_2",
        "enabled": false,
        "path": "rules_2.json"
      }]

   }
```

I have tried adding the "testList" to my rule file but it didn't work.

Comment: The syntax/structure of the file is wrong. It should be `[{...}, {...}, {...}]` where each `{...}` is a rule object. See [the example rules.json](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#:~:text=rules.json) in the documentation.